# Spring state machine to manage JPA entity

Tags: java, spring-statemachine

I have a `Task` JPA `@Entity` which has field `state` - so it looks like state machine could be good abstraction to work with. The `state` may change by calling a REST endpoint in form like `PUT /api/tasks/{id}/state`. I wanted to utilize the concept of `Actions`, `Guards` as it looks like nice abstractions. I guess I need something along:

1. In the REST endpoint create (or rather restore?) the state machine in state corresponding to the current `Tasks`'s state and associate the JPA entity with it's context so it is available for `Action`s which can change the `state` task's state field (and others) and persist it back through `Repository`
2. Send the event representing transition to new state

I assume point 1. will create the machine through builder as with @EnableStateMachineFactory you cannot really *create* the machine in particular state (which kind of make sense). I'm unclear how to add the entity which I probably `findOne` in `@Repository` to the state machine's context.

Would that be the right approach? Is there a sample covering this? I was pretty honest in going through the existing samples and didn't find anything similar.

Answer (score 4):

You should first ask yourself - do you *really*, **really** need a state machine for this (I don't know your full use case). The `StateMachine` will introduce some(a lot?) complexity in your code.

That being said, here's a possible design:

1) Implement your standard SOA for the Entity (e.g. `TaskController` -> `TaskService` -> `TaskRepository`).

2) Create a `Service (W)`, which solely purpose is to create events and send them to the SM. In that `Service (W)`, you will have the `SM factory` injected and the `TaskService` (for loading the state of an existing `Task`).

4) When Request/Event is sent to `TaskController`,  you will call the `Service (W)`, which will do the following:

- instantiate a new SM and if a `Task` exists, [rehydrate the state of the SM](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54707075/1007273) with the state of the task
- once the SM is initialized, send the event

5) In the state machine config, you will have source, target and action associated with that event. The action will call the `TaskService` and update the JPA entity.

This design makes sense if you have complex business rules when the Entity needs to be updated and you want the possible states transitions to be deterministic (e.g. you have a pre-defined workflow or state diagram).
The business rules before each state transition can be abstracted as guards and the SM can be the interface through which others are interacting (updating) with your JPA Entity.

For rehydrating state machine from JPA Entity, please [see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54707075/1007273).

Comment: If i understand correctly this suggestion will cause a spring circular dependency issue:

stateMachineConfig -> taskService -> stateMachineFactory

Comment: Not really - there are two ways to create state machine based on Configuration classes: EnableStateMachine and EnableStateMachineFactory. When you use the Factory interface the configuration of the SM instances that will be returned are defined in the Factory itself (overriding the appropriate 'configure' methods). So it should look like "taskService -> stateMachineFactory".

Answer (score -4):

May I suggest the tutorial at [Building REST Services with Spring](https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/rest/)?  If you work all the way through it, you will see how to add actions that depend on the state of the object while creating a REST-based service.

Comment: Thanks! I actually built a lot of rest services already. The point is that you need check whether transition state -> state is allowed and apply correct transition action. This is exactly where state machine could save you effort (hope)

Comment: The tutorial I mentioned includes a discussion and code for ResourceAssemblers, which enable you to write code to specify which actions are valid based on the state of the object being assembled, which is why I suggested the tutorial.

Comment: Without any offence - this is 100% off-topic :) Thanks for trying to help though.