# How to restore state machine from context builded in runtime?

Tags: java, spring, spring-statemachine

I have a state machine

```java
@EnableStateMachine
@Configuration
public class StateMachineConfiguration extends EnumStateMachineConfigurerAdapter<Status, Event> {
    @Override
    public void configure(StateMachineStateConfigurer<Status, Event> states) throws Exception {
        states.withStates()
                .initial(Status.DRAFT)
                .states(EnumSet.allOf(Status.class));
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(StateMachineTransitionConfigurer<Status, Event> transitions) throws Exception {
        transitions

                .withExternal()
                .target(Status.INVITATION).source(Status.DRAFT)
                .event(Event.INVITED)
                .guard(new Guard())
                .action(new ActionInvited())
                .and()

                .withExternal()
                .target(Status.DECLINED).source(Status.INVITATION)
                .event(Event.DECLINED)
                .action(new ActionDeclined());
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(StateMachineConfigurationConfigurer<Status, Event> config) throws Exception {
        config.withConfiguration().autoStartup(true);
    }
}
```

and I have a model, for example **Order**.
Model persists in DB. I extract model from DB, now my model has a status `Order.status == INVITATION`. I want to continue processing model with statemachine, but instance of statemachine will starts processing with initial state **DRAFT** but I needs continue processing from status **INVITATION**. In other words I want to execute

```java
stateMachine.sendEvent(MessageBuilder
  .withPayload(Event.DECLINED)
  .setHeader("orderId", order.id)
  .build()
)
```

and execute action `ActionDeclined()`. I don't want to persist a context of state machine in DB. I want to setting a state of stateMachine to state of my Model in runtime. How can I do that in right way? Using DefaultStateContext constructor or have an other, more beautiful way?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One possible approach is to create the `StateMachine` on the fly and to rehydrate the state machine from the DB using the state of the `Order`.
In this case you need to do the following steps:

- Resetting the `StateMachine` in all regions
- Load `Order` status from DB
- Create new [`DefaultStateMachineContext`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-statemachine/docs/current/api/org/springframework/statemachine/support/DefaultStateMachineContext.html) and populate accordingly

Let's assume you have a build method, which returns new state machines for processing order events (using a [StateMachineFactory](https://docs.spring.io/spring-statemachine/docs/current/reference/html/sm-factories.html)), but for an existing order, it will rehydrate the state from the database.

```
StateMachine<Status, Event> build(long orderId) {
  orderService.getOrder(orderId) //returns Optional
  .map(order -> {
     StateMachine<Status, Event> sm = stateMachineFactory.getStateMachine(Long.toString(orderId));
     sm.stop();
     rehydrateState(sm, sm.getExtendedState(), order.getStatus());
     sm.start();
     return sm;
   })
  .orElseGet(() -> createNewStateMachine(orderId);
}


void rehydrateState(StateMachine<Status, Event> newStateMachine, ExtendedState extendedState, Status orderStatus) {
  newStateMachine.getStateMachineAccessor().doWithAllRegions(sma ->
   sma.resetStateMachine(new DefaultStateMachineContext<>(orderStatus, null, null, extendedState));
  });
}
```

Comment: But why I need to recreating a state machine on the fly? I can work with already existing instance of the state machine and rehydrate that for every Order model, processing them one by one?

Comment: yes sure - you can do that. The logic applies to a single state machine. How you obtain an instance depends on the use cases. In my example it's just through a factory - that's all.

Comment: What is the cost of stopping and starting statemachine ? Is it resource/memory intensive ?

Comment: Developers of the Spring SM are stating that they have designed the state machines to be very light-weight objects and add minimal performance overhead. Of course every usecase should be considered separately. Best approach is to build a test-case suite that simulates users and then you can test different implementations and have metrics data.

Comment: @hovanessyan: how to rehydrate statemachine with nested regions

Comment: in the same way - there's no difference in the code

Comment: @hovanessyan doing this causes all transitions defined using @ OnTransition to stop working...

Comment: @hovanessyan, works fine now with some minor tweak
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73845348/transition-handlers-defined-using-ontransition-stop-working-when-statemachine-i